# Javascript/Ajax requests that execute database queries

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I need some recommendations with Ajax requests that execute database queries. Let's assume that we are calling a Javascript function that executes a PHP script and this script retrieves some data from MySQL in order to return it to the Javascript calling function and update the website content. I want to focus this question on the performance related to database queries so the question is:
Is a good practice to open a new connection for each script execution triggered by an Ajax request? This would be the flow:

- Ajax executes a PHP script
- PHP script opens a MySQL connection
- PHP script performs required queries
- PHP script closes MySQL connection
- PHP returns the result
- Javascript handles the result

Is there a better way to do this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: is there any other approach you/anyone  have which are going to use Javascript/Ajax apart from this. Com-on. Statements never have better or less. It only depends on the code what and how you used it.

Comment: @Anant I'm focusing the options in order to get the best performance. Thank you for commenting

Comment: Javascript/ajax have only this option, nothing else.

Comment: @Anant Okay, should I include PHP in the title? Maybe there's a better way to achieve better performance with other method in PHP.

Comment: php means page refresh, and javascript/ajax means no page refresh. The 2-5 will remain same in each approach, just 1-6 added into javascript/ajax concept. Both have there one pros-cons